# Experiencing difficult to reproduce bugs with jqUploader and am considering switching to Uploadify. Thoughts?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, uploader

I've used [jqUploader](http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/) for a while but I find that it will occasionally fail to work on certain browsers on *certain machines* or will not work properly when using HTTP Basic authentication. I've tired of trying to get this to work properly and am considering switching to another (hopefully) less buggy uploader. I've looked into [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and it so far seems promising. Have you experience with any alternatives to jqUploader including possibly Uploadify? If so, what are your thoughts and recommendations?

I would prefer that configuring any such uploader require knowledge of JavaScript and/or jQuery, and that it not be totally reliant on any one specific back-end technology. Built-in PHP compatibility is a plus.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend Uploadify. I have used it several of times on web pages and it has always fit my needs. You can allow the user to upload multiple files at once through ctrl + clicking on all the files and you can require the user to choose from files with specific file. While the files are uploading there an interface that is displayed which shows a queue of the files that are uploading with progress bars, and as the files are finished they are removed from the queue.